# Text spills outside of boundary of Rectangle in SwiftUI with overlay

Tags: ios, swiftui, overlay

I want Text 1 and Text 2 in the blue rectangle to be within the boundaries of the `Rectangle` but when using overlay it seems to spill outside of the given boundary. How can one fix this?

I tried `ZStack` as well but had the same result.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
                    .frame(width: 1, height: 55)
                Rectangle()
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 10)
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .frame(width: .infinity, height: 60)
                    .padding()
            }
            .overlay(
                HStack {
                    Text("Text 1")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Text 2")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place overlay in different place (order of modifiers is important!), like

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
                .frame(width: 1, height: 55)
            Rectangle()
                .stroke(lineWidth: 10)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .overlay(                     
                    HStack {                 // << here !!
                        Text("Text 1")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Text 2")
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                )
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 60)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

Tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15